# Home directory are deleted making lost+found

Tags: mount, data-recovery

I added new hard drive and I mounted it over /home.

But, after that, all of home directories are changed to lost+found.

How to recover them?

Comment: It may be your old directory is safe. If you mounted 'over' your old /home, the directories are not merged, the last mounted directory 'hides' the first, and when you `umount` you'll see the 'hidden' directory/files

Comment: Create a new folder (e.g. `mkdir /home/<your_userid>/newdisk`) and use this as mountpoint for the new drive. Then you can see both your old /home and your empty new drive.